# Why can I not show the year?

Tags: support, timestamps, dates

Why can I not see the complete date of posting?  The year part is not shown.  I prefer date/time to look like the ISO standard:

```
2013-07-04 21:15:33.1234
```

Is it a setup function that I have missed?

Comment: Just hover over the post date. It should show you the full year, month, day and exact time.

Comment: Oh @Bart, you and your aversion to screenshots.. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Mouse-over the relative date. The tooltip shows the ISO date.

[image: ISO date tooltip]

Comment: -1 for the screenshot.

Comment: -1 for incomplete FHRC

Comment: Seems to be a perfect FreeHand Reversed C to me @Lix?

Comment: And there I was, trying to not deface the avatar...

Comment: -1 Not enough jQuery

Comment: @Bart Free Hand Reverse **Circle** *facepalm*

Comment: I was hoping for a uniform display of date/time in the body of answers and comments without mousing over.  It is jarring to me to have several different formats when I'm scanning 'at speed'.

Comment: There isn't such a display. I personally prefer the relative times.

Comment: -1 Freehand circle too fat.